# EOL printing issue between oracle linux/unix server and windows server 2019/2012

Tags: linux, windows, oracle, plsql, printing

I'm working with a legacy system. It prints to metal tags (similar to stamped military dog tags). We upgraded the print server to 2019 recently, and also swapped the test database server from Redhat Linux to HP Unix. The metal tags printouts have started to print with double spaced lines.

The relavant PL/SQL looks something like this (note the end of line seems to be backwards)

```
-- XONOFF starts with STX
v_out := '<';

-- line #1 XONOFF needs only LF CR to seperate lines
v_out := v_out || 'some data' || chr(10) || chr(13);

-- line #2 XONOFF needs only LF CR to seperate lines
v_out := v_out || 'some more data' || chr(10) || chr(13);

-- XONOFF needs ETX at end of message and LF CR to help flush
v_out := v_out || '>' || chr(10) || chr(13);
utl_file.put(v_file, upper(v_out)); 
utl_file.fflush(v_file);
```

Testing it is difficult, due to limited resources we have:

Production:

- Production Database Server->Production Print Server->Production
  Printers
  "Test:"
- Test Database Server->Production Print Server->Production Printers

It initially broke when we upgraded the production print server to windows 2019. I reviewed the code and saw the LFCR inversion and assumed windows 2019 was thinking this inverted EOL was a linux EOL and automaticalled "fixed" it by changing the LF to CRLF, leaving us with CRLFCR and a bunch of extra lines added. The current workaround is we have production print server booted to Windows 2012, but the host is pushing hard to move to 2019.

I got everyone coordinated to do a test today, and prepared a few different versions of the print code to try, the first being one that swapped LFCR to CRLF. We rebooted the print server 2019 during lunch, confirmed that production was broken again, and it was. Then I did a baseline test on the test database server, expecting that to be broken too, but it worked. This derailed the test.

The only difference I'm aware of between the two setups is that the test database server is running Redhat instead of HP Unix. To clarify what's been tried:

- Test DB Server(Redhat RHEL 7.9) & Prod Print Server (Win 2012): Prints
  Normal
- Test DB Server(Redhat RHEL 7.9) & Prod Print Server (Win 2019): Prints
  Normal
- Prod DB Server(HP Unix) & Prod Print Server (Win 2012): Prints Normal
- Prod DB Server(HP Unix) & Prod Print Server (Win 2019): Prints Double
  Spaced

We want to eventually have the Production Print Server on 2019. We do want to update the Prod Database Server to Redhat also, which hypothetically would fix it.

I'm not confident the Redhat swap will fix it though, mostly cause I don't understand what is going wrong. I'm fairly certain it could be fixed with some tweaks to the EOL sequence in the code, but I couldn't test my code cause I can't recreate the error on test, and I can't run any changes in production either.

Does anyone have an suggestions or know what the issue is? Or even just have a gut instict as to what is going on? The XON XOFF stuff is perplexing to me too.

Comment: What does the printer documentation say?

Comment: Great idea. There’s a few different printers. I believe they’re decades old and maintained by a bunch of mechanics. I doubt they’ll have any documentation. In fact during testing we found out one of the printers had been cutting off the last couple characters of each line, and it’s been doing it for years. They have just been living with it apparently.

I’ll see if I can get manufacturer and model numbers from them at least.

Comment: The Printer (Matica C410) documentaion doesn't specifically discuss end of lines. However there's an example in the documentation that shows just a Line Feed, linux style. 

However, it also says you can print tags directly from Windows Notepad, which I would assume would use CRLF. In other words, its implying it handles both windows or linux style EOL.

It feels like it's something to do with the 2 servers or the interface between them.